# Replacing aspose JRPptExporterParameter.PPT_TEMPLATE_PRESENTATION in jasperreports 5.0

Tags: jasper-reports, export, powerpoint, aspose

I am generating a ppt report using jasperreports and aspose library (ppt exporter from aspose). I'm trying to eliminate aspose from the project and use the ppt exporter from jasperreports 5.0. The problem is that at the moment the generated report needs an external .pot file which is added using aspose:

```
com.aspose.slides.jasperreports.JRPptExporter exporter = new com.aspose.slides.jasperreports.JRPptExporter();
......
exporter.setParameter(com.aspose.slides.jasperreports.JRPptExporterParameter.PPT_TEMPLATE_PRESENTATION, pptTemplate);
exporter.exportReport();
```

I didn't find any similar parameter in JRExporterParameter from jasperreports and I couldn't find any efficient solution yet. Is there any method of using an external .pot file? I was thinking about creating a second JasperPrint object from the .pot file and then exporting both JasperPrint objects setting JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST

Comment: Andrei, can you please share why you want to exclude Aspose from your project? The Aspose.Slides for JasperReports provides a comprehensive solution and we can also help you if there is any issue with this component. Please note that I work as developer evangelist with Aspose.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that fits for you, but I've written a custom PPTX Exporter (only pptx, not binary ppt), which is based on Apache POI. The [POI element](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow.html#XMLSlideShow(java.io.InputStream)) can be initalized by your own template pptx (not yet implemented in my version).

https://code.google.com/p/pptx-shape-exporter/

Drop me a line, if this sounds interesting to you.